# How to show store timings in slots form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I have store timings coming in JSON format as below:

```
[   {
      "dayOfWeek":"MONDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

},
   {
      "dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY",
      "openTime":"06:30",
      "closeTime":"21:00"

}
]
```

I need to show timings on UI in form of slots (MONDAY-SUNDAY 14:00-20:00) as per screenshot below:

[image]

There can be multiple slots if timings are changed.

**Approach:**

```
const createBusinessHoursMap = (businessHours) => {
const openingHoursMap = new Map();
const openingHoursToDisplay = [];

businessHours.forEach((businessHour) => {
    const key = businessHour.openTime + " - " + businessHour.closeTime;
    if (!openingHoursMap.has(key)) {
        const value = [];
        value.push(businessHour.dayOfWeek);
        openingHoursMap.set(key, [...value]);
    } else if (openingHoursMap.has(key)) {
        openingHoursMap.get(key).push(businessHour.dayOfWeek);
    }
});

for (let [key, value] of openingHoursMap) {
    const timings = key;
    const days = [...value];
    if (days.length > 1) {
        openingHoursToDisplay.push(
            <React.Fragment>
                <br />
                &nbsp;<font>{days[0] + " - " + days[days.length - 1]}</font>&nbsp;
                <font>{timings}</font>
                <br />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    } else if (days.length === 1) {
        openingHoursToDisplay.push(
            <React.Fragment>
                <br />
                &nbsp;<font>{days[0]}</font>&nbsp;
                <font>{timings}</font><span />
                <br />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
};
return openingHoursToDisplay;
};
```

*Code Explanation:*

I am leveraging [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), key being `openTime-closeTime` and value being the array of days falling in that particular timings.

Now iterating over Map and if days array length is greater than 1, pushing react element containing first and last index of days array (value of Map) and timings (key of Map) to another array `openingHoursToDisplay`.

**Problem:**

For Example: Monday to Friday has timings 08:00-21:00 *excluding* Wednesday. On UI it'll be shown like:

Monday-Friday 08:00-21:00

Wednesday 09:00-22:00 (For example Wednesday has this timings)

From UI perspective it's not the correct information being shown to user as at first glance it seems like Monday-Friday includes Wednesday as well.

**Question:**

How can I properly show this information to user?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes, most welcome, in fact I need this solution.

Comment: I have handled a similar issue before. And I created an NPM package for that. Here is the source code, I hope this will help. 
https://github.com/oahehc/openinghour-shorten/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If collapsing consequent days, having the same `openTime` and `closeTime`, works for you, you can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce()` method.

Following is a distilled demo:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const sampleData = [{"dayOfWeek":"MONDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","openTime":"09:00","closeTime":"22:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"SATURDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"},{"dayOfWeek":"SUNDAY","openTime":"08:00","closeTime":"21:00"}]

const Component = ({openingHours}) => {
  const hours = openingHours
    .reduce((r, {dayOfWeek, openTime, closeTime}, i, s) => (
      i && s[i-1].closeTime == closeTime && s[i-1].openTime == openTime ?
      r[r.length-1].days.push(dayOfWeek) :
      r.push({days:[dayOfWeek], openTime, closeTime}),
    r), [])
    .reduce((r,{days,openTime,closeTime}) => (
      days.length > 1 ?
      r.push(
        `${[days.shift(),days.pop()]
          .map(day => day.slice(0,1)+day.slice(1).toLowerCase())
          .join(!days.length ? ', ' : '-')} ${openTime}-${closeTime}`) :
      r.push(
        `${days[0].slice(0,1)+days[0].slice(1).toLowerCase()} ${openTime}-${closeTime}`),
    r),[])
  
  return (
    <div>{hours.map((e,i) => <div key={i}>{e}</div>)}</div>
  )
}

render(<Component openingHours={sampleData} />, rootNode)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Unable to run code snippet here. Getting error:


`{
  "message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1,
  "colno": 1
}`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for it. Can you please explain code a bit as well?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen : Sure, is there anything specific puzzling you?

Comment: `r, {dayOfWeek, openTime, closeTime}, i, s` r, i, s, can you please tell meaningful name of those variables?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen : You may refer to [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for details. In a nutshell, those are aggregated variable handed over (and modified) on each loop iteration, index of the current element of source array being processed and source array itself.